# Purescript: why can't genericEncodeJSON encode types inside a container?

Tags: purescript

I don't understand why the below program fails to compile.

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
import Foreign.Generic (defaultOptions, genericEncodeJSON)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  log "Hello sailor!"

newtype Foo = Foo {
    x :: Int
  , y :: Int
  , z :: Array Bar
}

type Bar = {
    a :: String
  , b :: String
}

derive instance repGenericFoo:: Generic Foo _

fooToJSON :: Foo -> String
fooToJSON = genericEncodeJSON $ defaultOptions { unwrapSingleConstructors = true }
```

This is the output by the compiler

```
Compiling Main
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs line 27, column 13 - line 27, column 30

  No type class instance was found for

    Foreign.Class.Encode { a :: String
                         , b :: String
                        }
```

If Array is not used, then the program compiles

```
newtype Foo = Foo {
    x :: Int
  , y :: Int
  , z :: Bar
}

type Bar = {
    a :: String
  , b :: String
}
```

why is it that genericEncodeJSON can't encode Bar if it's inside a container like Array or List?

Comment: I don’t know anything about purescript but In Haskell, `Foo` could not be a newtype and `Bar` is missing a constructor (or are JS-style objects allowed as types in purescript?)

Comment: @DanRobertson In purescript {} is a synonym for Record which is a type constructor.

Comment: What if you derive `Generic Bar` too?

Comment: @DanRobertson Deriving Generic Bar also doesn't compile (same error). If I make Bar an instance of Foreign.Class.Encode it compiles, but it defeats the purpose as I want to serialize my data automatically.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and I've created an issue in their repo https://github.com/paf31/purescript-foreign-generic/issues/59 . By any chance, were you be able to solve it?